# how does the call to overriden methods take place in case of dynamic dispatch

Tags: java

```
class a extends b {
    void h() {
        System.out.println("class a");
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        b x = new a();
        c y = new b();
        c z = new a();

        x.h();      //output class a
        y.h();      //output class b
        z.h();      //output class a
    }
}

class b extends c {
    void h() {
        System.out.println("class b");
    }
}
class c {
    void h() {
        System.out.println("class c");
    }
}
```

Whats is the precedence in which it checks which method to call. I am confused as to how the JVM decides which method to call when I use dynamic dispatch. The output in this case is

```
class a
class b
class a
```

and when I remove the overridden method from class a the output is

```
class b
class b
class b
```

Comment: Could you please clean up the spacing a bit?

Comment: This code does not compile- `b x= new a();` is illegal.

Comment: ok lemme check the code i just copy pasted from eclipse...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class used depends on the instantiated type.  So if you have an instance of class a (via new a()), then whether the declared variable is of type a, b, or c does not matter for the purpose of which definition of h() is invoked (it will always invoke a.h()).

However, where the declared type does matter is in when choosing an overloaded method. If you have a subclass that overloads an overridden method, then when invoking from a variable declared as the parent class, you will never use the overloaded method.  If using a variable declared as being of the subclass, then it will use the overloaded method as appropriate.

Comment: Doesn't it take into account the object type as I am storing a subclass reference in a parent class type object :-o  ... I thought during dynamic dispatch they call the method depending upon the object type..thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You will always invoke the method of the instantiated type (which may or may not be inherited or overridden), regardless of the declared type (assuming the method exists in the declared type).  However, if the method is overloaded in the subtype then the declared type of the object WILL matter (invoking from an instance declared as of the parent type will not use the overloaded method, whereas if the object is declared as being of the subtype it will).