# Confusion over how base class finds the correct method in dynamic dispatch for overridden methods with vtable implementations

Tags: c++, late-binding, dynamic-dispatch

This question can be summed up as: **where is the missing arrow?**

I was reading Chapter 4 of  *A Tour of C++* 2nd Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup and couldn't understand how a base pointer to a derived object was able to find the correct method to call when it came to virtual functions. Here's the example provided for 2 derived classes from `Container`.

```cpp
class Container {
public:
    virtual double& operator[](int) = 0; // pure virtual function
    virtual int size() const = 0; // const member function (§4.2.1)
    virtual ~Container() {} // destr uctor (§4.2.2)
};
```

[image: vtbl in Stroustrup book]

The function that will be used for `Container`-like object is:

```
void use(Container& c)
{
const int sz = c.size();
for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
    std::cout << c[i] << '\n';
}
```

I understand that `vtables` or virtual function tables are an implementation detail and are not part of the C++ standard. It is the implementation detail that I would like to understand.

I didn't understand how a pointer to a base class as a function parameter would allow a derived class instance argument so I went on to search other explanations. [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/hS7kPtVB1vI?si=NGUa76AYjPrDr9a5) shows another drawing where the vtable pointer is mentioned but doesn't quite go into detail as to how a `Base*` figures out a `Derived` object.

The confusion I have is that, to me, t would seem to make sense for `Base*` to have pointers to all the other methods of the derived classes so that when the pointer is called, it could do a "cast" (in quotes because I don't think a cast is efficient) and then figure out the correct method to call. However, this seems convoluted and a "cast" would be expensive. In the example below, it seems like `Base*` has some information about what it is pointing to but there is no arrow to the derived class vtable. How does it know that it is pointing to a derived object as there are no arrows in the diagram below? Is there an arrow missing in the illustration?

[image: drawing of vtable]

[This tutorial](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/) has a similar representation but I can't seem to get where the "missing" arrow is. From my understanding, there is only one of `Class B` and `Class C` blueprints and that each new object uses this to create its own copy so we would have the blueprints in memory and the actual instances in the heap/free store when we use `new`.
[image: extra diagram]

To make sure I don't get downvoted for not doing research. Here are some questions I have looked at that mentioned dynamic dispatch: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093205/static-dynamic-binding-and-static-dynamic-dispatch-are-a-bit-confusing), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393817/how-does-the-call-to-overriden-methods-take-place-in-case-of-dynamic-dispatch). They are all for `Java` not `C++`.

Comment: The derived object sets up base's vptr to point to the derived's vtable. It is done at construction time

Comment: `Base* figures out a Derived object.` Base doesn't aware of Derived. `Base* p = new Derived; p->use();` calls the actual `Derived::use()` set in the vtable while Derived creation. `Derived::use()` knows about Derived, `this` in it has the type `Derived*`.

Comment: I guess the person with the bad handwriting forgot to draw the arrow, that's why it's missing. Or maybe it's a video, and he draws it later.

Comment: "From my understanding, there is only one of Class B and Class C blueprints and that each new object uses this to create its own copy so we would have the blueprints in memory and the actual instances in the heap/free store when we use new." At least in the usual implementation, each class has only one vtable in memory, and each time you create an object of that type, its vtable pointer is initialized to point to the one and only vtable for that class.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, do you mean that in the case of `Base * instance = new Derived`, the `Derived` object has a vtable pointer that points to the `class` vtable in memory? And the `Base` pointer just points to the `Derived` object?

Comment: @heretoinfinity: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @anatolyg, I watched the full video before posting the question. There are no more arrows drawn.